# Digits of even number should be an even number

Tags: python

I need to print all even numbers from certain range (Eg. 2000 to 4000). But, the condition is, 'All the digits of that number should be an even number'(Eg. 2222, 2468). In this case, Zero('0') doesn't a matter.

I have tried this:

```
start = int(input("Enter the start of range: ")) 
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: ")) 
for num in range(start, end + 1): 
if num % 2 == 0: 
    print(num, end = " ")
```

Above code only prints all even numbers.

I hope you all understand. Any Ideas Please...?

Comment: There are multiple ways of solving this. The most intuitive is checking every digit in the number instead of the entire number itself. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't have any idea to do this. Any other way to do this?? @Metareven

Comment: The regex solution is undoubtedly better, but if you can't use Regex, you could just use sets. `len(set('02468').union(set(str(num)))) == 5`  will be True for all numbers comprised only of even digits. This was closed before I could post an answer, but if you change `num % 2 == 0` in your code with this, it will give you the answer you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to convert the number in a string to access each digit, please find below an idea.

```
start = int(input("Enter the start of range: ")) 
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: ")) 
for num in range(start, end + 1):
  txt = str(num) #Convert number in string to acces each digit
  j=0
  for i in range(len(txt)):
    if int(txt[i]) % 2 == 0: 
      j+= 1
  if j == len(txt):
    print(int(txt), end = " ")
```

Comment: It prints  2
4
6
8
0
2
4
6
8
2
0
2
2
2   (It prints only each even digit of a number)

Comment: Yes, it was an idea. Please try again. I added an improvement.

Answer (score 5):

If you are open to a regex solution, you could try:

```
for num in range(1, 50): 
    if re.search(r'^[02468]+$', str(num)):
        print(str(num) + " ")
```

This printed:

```
2
4
6
8
20
22
24
26
28
40
42
44
46
48
```

Note that we don't have to bother an additional check of the modulus two of the number, since having all even digits guarantees that the number must be even.

Comment: It shows an error "'re' is not defined"

Comment: Add `import re` to the top of your Python script.

Comment: After importing re It works well...Thank u so much....:):) @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Here is annother way to do it by casting each number as a string to check each digit:

```
import numpy as np

valid_numbers = []
for i in range(1, 50):
    valid_number = False
    if np.mod(i,2)==0:
        valid_number = True
        str_ = str(i)
        for digit in str_:
            if np.mod(int(digit),2)!=0:
                valid_number=False
    if valid_number:
        valid_numbers.append(i)
```

---

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48]
```

Comment: It shows an error like "'np' is not defined"

Comment: you should mention what is `np`

Comment: You're right, I added the library name (np = numpy big surprise ;) )

Answer (score 0):

The following function checks if all digits in a number are even

```
def all_even_digits(n):
    while n != 0:
        # Extract the right most digit of n
        digit = n % 10

        # If the digit is odd return False
        if digit % 2 != 0:
            return False

        # Remove the rightmost digit from n
        n = n // 10

    # Since no digit in n was odd
    return True
```

We can now use the `all_even_digits` function to check each number within the `start` and `end` range.

```
for num in range(start, end):
    if all_even_digits(num):
        print(num)
```

Comment: It works well....Thank u so much...:):) @Parth Sharma

Comment: No problem :) @EmeraldCaroDythosh